# Is Unvested Money in a 401(k) counted as income?

Tags: 401k, roth-401k

I left my job during the middle of 2011. I had $5,000 from the company contributed to my Roth 401(k) as part of a profit-sharing plan in March 2011, but only $2,000 was vested.

I am trying to figure out if my MAGI includes that $3,000 that was unvested.

Does this full amount of $5,000 still count as "earnings?" Or is only the $2,000 considered earnings and the tax forms they sent me in January will show that?

Answer (score 4):

No, unvested money returns to the employer, its not yours. They should send you W2 which will only show the actual (vested) monies you got.

Comment: Thanks, but...let's say I didn't leave the company in 2011. What would my W2 say then, only the vested portion and then the following year when another $1,000 vests it would show up on my 2012 W2?

Comment: @Daniel - yes. You pay taxes on the money when it becomes yours, i.e.: when it is vested. Until then it is deposited, but doesn't belong to you and cannot be considered income.

Answer (score 0):

The company match is not earnings. My company deposits 5% of my income into my 401(k) and it appears nowhere except on the paperwork for the 401(k). 
To be clear, it doesn't appear on any paystub or W2.

Comment: I believe that's true for 401K, but the question may be relevant for any "unvested" benefits for a leaving employee, like stock options or RSU's.